# How do I handle a question that's not very good but the user deleted a significant portion of it (including code)?

Tags: discussion, edits, low-quality-posts

I noticed this question over the weekend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074340/the-output-displays-zero-instead-of-processing-the-calculation-method. When I first saw it and the answer, I was rather confused. I dug into the revision history and found that the user had *deleted the code that caused the problem* from the question. The result is that the accepted answer is out of context, and it's rather difficult to see where the answer came from.

In response, I rolled back the edit and left a comment explaining why. Now the user has applied the *same* (or a very similar) edit, removing the code again.

Not wanting to get into an argument or an edit war, I was about to flag for moderator attention (since there's no way I know of for the community to prevent a user from editing their own question). Then I remembered that the question is of pretty low quality, anyway. I currently have a close vote on it. (I believe I used the "typo" reason.)

So the basic idea (to put it in a more reusable context) is that there are two things going on.

1. It's a bad question, and
2. the OP is making edits that actively detract from it, in spite of my attempts to deal with that.

My options seem to be:

- Forget about the edits. The question is too bad to bother with them. The community will likely close it, and it may even be deleted.
- Flag for attention to deal with the edit problem.

What course of action is most in line with StackOverflow's goals and intended usage?

Comment: Why forget about the edits? The question is for other people as well, and the question should be in the best shape possible. It can be closed as well if need be.

Comment: @remyabel That is precisely what I'm asking. =) I suppose the point I didn't really raise is that it's liable to get closed anyway and possibly auto-deleted. Editing that into the question.

Comment: I would flag that in a heartbeat. Close-worthy or not; a user shouldn't be vandalizing their own posts; period. A lot of times this is a student trying to avoid a plagarism check.

Comment: Sometimes it is an employee trying to remove proprietary information. Even then, I'd still disagree about the removal - if you want consultancy you should hire a consultant. The price we ask for offering help on SO is a small one - let others learn from your questions.

Comment: Having looked at the question I disagree that it's low quality. It's actually a good indirect question about if..else ambiguity and the importance of braces. The answer however is not good quality. It's shallow and doesn't explain why the braces fix the issue or how the language interprets the code without braces.

Comment: @slebetman I can accept that there's an argument that it could be salvageable. However, as a giant code dump, I think we would be hard pressed to call it "good quality." I suspect there's a much better example of the behavior elsewhere on the site, in which case you might be more inclined to close as duplicate than as a "typo."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flag the question. You left a comment explaining why you rolled back and the OP didn't listen. It's best not to engage in a rollback/edit war and just let a moderator handle it. The close reason you chose:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be
>   reproduced or a simple typographical error**.

...doesn't make sense since it's not reflected in the current question. Be sure to explain in your flag reason *why* the post should be locked.